# Facebook "like" button on comments

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to implement the Facebook like and share functionality for "liking" the comments of other users on a website? Does every comment has to have a permalink?

Answer (score 6):

I have asked the question on Facebook developers forum, and they have come back to me with this response.  Basically, the functionality that is required is not available.

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=316205#p316205

Answer (score 5):

### Intro:

---

You will need individual like buttons for every comment, and as @Fnatte says you can then reference them to the comment by giving it an ID like `#com1`,`#com2`etc...

The best way to achieve this is through a `for` loop (I imagine you are pulling from a DB) that will iterate through and add the relevant code for the like button and implement the URL based on the comment it is pulling,

### The Code:

---

You have 2 options, `<iframe>`:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;font=segoe+ui&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

This is VERY slow, especially if you have a lot of comments loading at the same time, it does mean you don't need to import their JS library though,

Then there is the FB JS SDK:

```html
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://example.com" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="90" font="segoe ui" colorscheme="dark"></fb:like>
```

This I would argue is a more eficcient way of doing things, but it does require a *bit* more time and effort - but will be well worth it.

The script of course can be imported only once in the head and then used multiple times throughout the page (perfect for what you need).

The URL to like is based on both the URL in the address bar and the ID that you have assigned to the code (e.g. #comment1) so the URL you are liking looks like this: `http://mypage.com/page#comment1`

### Further Reading:

---

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Good luck and I hope this helps!

Comment: How can you set a `href` tag to like someones comment?

Comment: @Ardman - I imagine it is trivial, by liking CSS ID class that is linked to the page. e.g. http://mypage.com/page1#comment1, http://mypage.com/page1#comment2 etc...

Comment: Arent the comments contained within the `fb:comments` control

Comment: @Ardman - Oh it seems I misunderstood, I assumed he was using a 3rd party comment plugin (e.g. WordPress) where a loop pulls the comments from a DB, then he could just insert like buttons for every comment within the loop?

Answer (score 4):

> - **DEMO & SOURCE** http://so.devilmaycode.it/facebook-like-button-on-comments/

updated, hope this help

Answer (score 3):

I have never done it myself but you should probably check out http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#plugins.

It looks like you would need a unique link for each comment.
You could try including a fragment identifier in every URL like:

http://domain.com/article1#comment1
http://domain.com/article1#comment2

Answer (score 3):

[Facebook has rolled out a new version of the comments plugin which supports advanced functionality such as "liking" and replying to other comments.](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472/) In addition, replies to a comment made on Facebook.com are now pushed back to the comments plugin (hosted on another site.)

How to enable:

```html
Add the migrated attribute:
<fb:comments xid="YOUR_XID" migrated="1"></fb:comments>

OR use the href attribute instead of xid for future comments boxes
<fb:comments href="YOUR_CANONICAL_URL"></fb:comments>
```

References:

- [New <fb:comments>](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)
- [Legacy <fb:comments>](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments/)